# Encryption length

Tags: security, encryption

Does the encryption length of the hash encrypted influence his own security?

I mean if i use md5() or sha() if the returned hash has 35 chars or 55 chars does will this influence in some way security of hash?

Comment: It depends on the `Encryption Algorithem`.

Comment: Do you really mean an [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) that is by definition reversible? Or do you mean a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like MD5 and SHA-1 which are not reversible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash don't have a "security", as they generally can't be inverted.
What they do have is risk of collision, i.e. two different messages (filenames, passwords etc.) mapping to the same hash.
To prevent that, the more bits you have, the better, provided that hash distribution is as flat (spread out) as possible.

In that case, collision probability is approximately the reciprocal of the bit length: a 32 bit hash is 1/2**32, etc.

There are also other considerations: under certain circumstances it is possible to craft a collision against MD5, and SHA is therefore to ne preferred. The difficulty of the attack is very high, and so you can still use MD5 for most purposes except very high security scenarios.